# Phonegap: Uploading an image to server using backbone

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, backbone.js

I am building a **Phonegap** Application and for client side MVC I am using Backbone. My App is using camera for clicking images then it uploads that images to the server. 
However Phonegap provides us an option to upload images to server  using `FileTransfer()` but since I am already using Backbone thats why I needs something integrated with Backbone. So that I can easily upload it just using the `save` method and utilize the already build Backbone.sync feature.

Comment: Is there some way to send image  using "File Uri" and not using base-64 Data as it causes memory error in iphone